# Slide whole div down rather than reveal on slideDown/slideUp

Tags: jquery, css, show, slidedown

I have a function that when the header reaches a certain div when scroll down, the logo slides down onto the navbar. This works but using the jQuery slide down seems to 'reveal' the div rather than showing the whole div at once and sliding that div down.

What it's doing is normal as i'm using the elements from here:

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

But i am after like this example when hovered over navigation: http://aaronjwood.com/

Is there another way using JQuery of css? Any links would be great!

Here is my jQuery to support my question:

```
$(".logo .visible").hide(); 

    var topOfOthDiv = $("#home-2").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $(".logo .visible").slideDown(300); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }else{
            $(".logo .visible").slideUp(300);
        }
    });
```

logo css:

```
h1.logo {
    width:126px;
    height:58px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 40px;
    margin-left:40px;

}

.logo .visible{
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#2e2e2e;
    background:url(../images//logo.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

html

```
<div id="nav">
        <div class="nav_wrapper">
        <h1 class="logo"><div class="visible"></div></h1>
            <ul id="navigation">
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

In the js fiddle, when the item is clicked on, the panel "reveals" itself rather then sliding the div down as whole (like the example link further up ^^). Hope this makes sense.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sVCvF/

Comment: Could you setup a [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your issue? Your HTML doesn't provide enough to go on, so I'm unsure the problem, though it "appears" as if it should work fine.

Comment: js fiddle example is added :)

Comment: LOL, now i'm more confused, the jsFiddle you posted does exactly what it's supposed to do just right. What is your expected result, cause I'm trying to help figure this out, but I just don't see the "problem" yet?

Comment: You obviously didn't read his question then. He wants to SLIDE the div down without it resizing it's height.

Comment: It's hard to explain i'm sorry! As you can see in the link the panel is revealing with the text in it. Imagine the div the full size and animating 'down'. My website example has a logo image,and the image slidesDown as it's revealing the image rather than sliding the div down. The http://aaronjwood.com/ the content in the sliding dix seems to be fixed in the div and scrolls down rather than revealing the content inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `slideDown` you can use `animate` to slide it down.
 for example u can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/sVCvF/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").on('click', function(){
      $("#panel").animate({'margin-top': 0}, 1000);
  });
});
```

you do need to use some tweaking on this code

Comment: I've sorted it using your example and in a previous comment i used the words 'animate' and 'top' so i was nearly there! Will post my code once it's refined. Thank you

Comment: I have included the jQuery in my script and it's great but for some strange reason, it takes ages to slide down even when i change it to fast and it's only on animate margin-top and slides back up fine? I have included my code in your answer. Thanks

Comment: Ahh seems to only be on firefox - will have to research!